# Display just 3 records instead of all in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, rendering

I want to display three records and randomly three record from model. But if I do this,

```
   {% for service in services.all %}
        {{service.title}}<br/>
        {{service.summary}}<br/>
   {% endfor %}
```

it display all records.

what I need to do display three 3 records from the database Django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Slice the queryset

```
{% for service in services.all|slice:"0:3" %}
```

It takes first 3 values form queryset.

if you need random, use

```
services = MOdel.objects.all().order_by('?')


{% for service in services | slice:"0:3" %}
```

in view and pass it to context or try this

```
{% for service in services.all | slice:"0:3" | dictsort:"?" %}
```

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) warn that `order_by('?')` can be slow, but if you don't have many services, then it might work OK in practice.

Comment: If you are randomizing in the view, you may as well slice at the same time: `.order_by('?')[:3]`

Comment: Thank you to all, but @Alasdair and @Adharsh your suggestions work for me perfectly. But @Adharsh when I'm doing this `{% for service in services.all|slice:"0:3" %}` it gives me this error `slice requires 2 arguments, 1 provided` now which one parameter is missing?